# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: native memory exhausted

Tags: out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am running a jar file that copies data from oracle to destination server(ElasticSearch). link text I am running this jar on AIX box :

> /oradata/slscrmit/tally> oslevel -s

7100-04-03-1642

> uname -a
> AIX mila 1 7 00F79AB04C00.

I get this Error when I run the jar file:
Command used to run:
`java -Xms3g -Xmx3g -Xmn1g -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MetaspaceSize=500m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=500m -XX:SurvivorRatio=2 -jar -Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:log4j2.xml -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 BoltESTally-1.4.3-Ver-1.0.jar` 
initload.

====================ERROR===============

> JVMDUMP039I Processing dump event "systhrow", detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError" at 2017/12/15 08:24:21 - please wait. JVMDUMP032I JVM requested System dump using '/oradata/slscrmit/tally/core.20171215.082421.39781194.0001.dmp' in response to an event Note: "Enable full CORE dump" in smit is set to FALSE and as a result there will be limited threading information in core file. JVMDUMP010I System dump written to /oradata/slscrmit/tally/core.20171215.082421.39781194.0001.dmp JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Heap dump using '/oradata/slscrmit/tally/heapdump.20171215.082421.39781194.0002.phd' in response to an event JVMDUMP010I Heap dump written to /oradata/slscrmit/tally/heapdump.20171215.082421.39781194.0002.phd JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Java dump using '/oradata/slscrmit/tally/javacore.20171215.082421.39781194.0003.txt' in response to an event JVMDUMP010I Java dump written to /oradata/slscrmit/tally/javacore.20171215.082421.39781194.0003.txt JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Snap dump using '/oradata/slscrmit/tally/Snap.20171215.082421.39781194.0004.trc' in response to an event JVMDUMP010I Snap dump written to /oradata/slscrmit/tally/Snap.20171215.082421.39781194.0004.trc JVMDUMP013I Processed dump event "systhrow", detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError". Dec 15, 2017 8:24:23 AM org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyInternalESLogger warn WARNING: Unexpected exception in the selector loop. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: native memory exhausted at sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateDBBMemory(Native Method) at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.(DirectByteBuffer.java:127) at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:311) at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.SocketReceiveBufferAllocator.newBuffer(SocketReceiveBufferAllocator.java:64) at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.SocketReceiveBufferAllocator.get(SocketReceiveBufferAllocator.java:41) at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:62) at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108) at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318) at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89) at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785).

=============================================

SVMON OUTPUT:

Pid Command          Inuse      Pin     Pgsp  Virtual 64-bit Mthrd  16MB
24315106 java            796276    11137        0   779119      N     Y     N

```
 PageSize                Inuse        Pin       Pgsp    Virtual

 s    4 KB               18356        225          0       1199

 m   64 KB               48620        682          0      48620
 L   16 MB                   0          0          0          0
 S   16 GB                   0          0          0          0

Vsid      Esid Type Description              PSize  Inuse   Pin Pgsp Virtual
```

169bfe6         4 work shared memory segment        m   4096     0    0    4096

84ba04         e work shared memory segment        m   4096     0    0    4096

1025d8c         7 work shared memory segment        m   4096     0    0    4096

13225a5         6 work shared memory segment        m   4096     0    0    4096

119a981         c work shared memory segment        m   4096     0    0    4096

14349c         8 work shared memory segment        m   4096     0    0    4096

1c2ed4e         d work shared memory segment        m   4096     0    0    4096

2e9eaf         9 work shared memory segment        m   4096     0    0    4096

7854f1         5 work shared memory segment        m   4096     0    0    4096

f2b266         f work shared memory segment        m   4095     0    0    4095

181650e         a work shared memory segment        m   4090     0    0    4090

1d42b52         3 work working storage              m   2681     0    0    2681

20002         0 work kernel segment               m    743   681    0     743

===================================================:
I have enough space on my Aix box:
vmstat:

System configuration: lcpu=128 mem=256512M

kthr    memory              page              faults        cpu

---

r  b   avm   fre  re  pi  po  fr   sr  cy  in   sy  cs us sy id wa

6  1 27345787 25280860   0   0   0   0    0   0 1747 28990 59128  8  3 89  0

> NON-PROD:!:_mila:/oradata/slscrmit/tally> oslevel -s

uname -a

7100-04-03-1642

NON-PROD:!:_mila:/oradata/slscrmit/tally> uname -a

AIX mila 1 7 00F79AB04C00

There is space in filestyatem as well:
/dev/slscrmit_oradt   2118.50   2024.41     94.09   96% /oradata/slscrmit

[image]

Comment: What is your question?   Also I note the lack of source code

Comment: I want to resolve this error:        java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: native memory exhausted at sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateDBBMemory(Native Method) at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this:::

Root Cause:
32 bit JVM has technical limitations on expanding java heap memory and native memory to more than 2GB.
The setenv.sh file contained. "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java8/bin “  , which was pointing to 32 bit JVM

Solution:
Goal is to point to  64bit JVM.
Also check that the kernel bit mode is 64bit? Using command getconf KERNEL_BITMODE
Verify 64bit JVM version using command :

## java -d64 -version

Correct setenv.sh to point to 64bit jvm on all AIX boxes, export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java8_64
Make sure other entries in this file point to this JAVA_HOME.

Now run the jar and specify command line params with desired heap size. I was able to run this with 10g heap size.